# Firebase not creating any child in Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a child i added to my firebase realtime database But i am not getting anything and i dont know why . i made sure to implement and call firebase correctly .[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKkv3.png)

```
 if(task.isSuccessful()){
    
                            User user = new User(username,email,password);
    
                            String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            database.child("Users").child(id).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
```

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me1mK.png)

Comment: Just to understand. Have you tried to output the database reference to see if it the same of https://chit-chat... .firebasedatabase.app? If it's not the same it means you are not referring to that database

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Comment: can you please share the full snippet which include everything related with db you are doing

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors in the logcat

Comment: As I already said, did you check your database reference? What's the output of FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().toString() ?

Comment: Is getException().getMessage() in the Toast displaying somethig?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firebase real-time database "rules". Make sure that your database must be allowed to read and write data.

Comment: This is my database default rule.{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1623261600000",  // 2021-6-10
    ".write": "now < 1623261600000",  // 2021-6-10
  }
}